# Ho to display chart in details band in jasper?

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I am using grouping logic. I have grouped my details and I want to display chart for the details but chart should be beside the details.It is displayed properly in group footer band but i want to display in details band, Please find the screens and give your suggestions.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Keep chart in summary band only to avoid any bad functioning

Comment: Thanks.. That will definitely work but I want to display it with data in details only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can display the chart in detail band using the background band.

Just make sure the place you want to see it from the background.